# Reference parent object while deserializing a JSON using Gson

Tags: java, json, gson, deserialization

Given the following JSON:

```
{
    "authors": [{
        "name": "Stephen King",
        "books": [{
            "title": "Carrie"
        }, {
            "title": "The Shining"
        }, {
            "title": "Christine"
        }, {
            "title": "Pet Sematary"
        }]
    }]
}
```

And this object structure:

```
public class Author {
    private List<Book> books;
    private String name;
}

public class Book {
    private transient Author author;
    private String title;
}
```

Is there a way, using the Google Java library Gson, to deserialize the JSON and that the books objects has a reference to the "parent" author object?

Is it possible **without** using a custom deserializer?

- If yes: How?
- If no: Is is still possible to do it with a custom deserializer?

Comment: `Is it possible without using a custom deserializer? ` i don't think it's possible, given the nature how gson deserialize. `Is is still possible to do it with a custom deserializer?` yes, it is possible to do so. just look for tutorials regarding that part, stackoverflow had several question and answer regarding this topic.

Comment: @Tezla Can you point me one article or a stackoverflow that explain how I can achieve that because I didn't find anything on that. That's why I decide to post my question. It'll help me a lot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this case, I would implement a custom `JsonDeserializer` for the parent object, and propagate the `Author` info, like so:

```
public class AuthorDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Author> {
    @Override
    public Author deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        final JsonObject authorObject = json.getAsJsonObject();

        Author author = new Author();
        author.name = authorObject.get("name").getAsString();

        Type booksListType = new TypeToken<List<Book>>(){}.getType();
        author.books = context.deserialize(authorObject.get("books"), booksListType);

        for(Book book : author.books) {
            book.author = author;
        }

        return author;
    }   
}
```

Note that my example omits error checking. You would use it like so:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(Author.class, new AuthorDeserializer())
    .create();
```

To show it working, I pulled off just the "authors" key from your example JSON, allowing me to do this:

```
JsonElement authorsJson  = new JsonParser().parse(json).getAsJsonObject().get("authors");

Type authorList = new TypeToken<List<Author>>(){}.getType();
List<Author> authors = gson.fromJson(authorsJson, authorList);
for(Author a : authors) {
    System.out.println(a.name);
    for(Book b : a.books) {
        System.out.println("\t " + b.title + " by " + b.author.name);
    }
}
```

Which printed:

```
Stephen King
     Carrie by Stephen King
     The Shining by Stephen King
     Christine by Stephen King
     Pet Sematary by Stephen King
```

Comment: It is so simple! How did I didn't think about it. Thanks a lot

Comment: But what if the Author object as many fields and I dont want to map them all manually. And also I dont want to change the deserializer each time I change the Author object. What do you suggest ?

Comment: @Thermech - I'm not sure there's a way around that with GSON. Your other option is to do the default deserialization, and then post-process the result. You *could* create a constructor for `Author` that takes a `JsonObject` and use that to populate the primitive fields, keeping that logic within the `Author` class. Similarly, you could create a constructor that takes all of the primitive types as parameters, which would force you to update the deserializer when you made changes to the class.